# writing a matrix class in r into a column in csv

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I am using Random forest for modelling. I get feature importance of the variables as below. This comes as a matrix class.

```
Importance <- model$importance
```

This returns the below matrix

```
                   %IncMSE     IncNodePurity
Col1             0.000000000       0.00000
Col2             0.021071302      48.26649
Col3             0.023357536      67.61509
col4             0.004547066      12.59772
col5             0.010846549     108.35169
```

I have another variable `Date` which is `Sys.Date()`.
I created a dataframe

```
DataFrame <- data.frame(Date, Importance)
```

My objective is to keep appending the date and feature importance, row wise in a single csv file.

I used the below command

```
write.table(DataFrame,"filename.csv", append=TRUE, sep=',')
```

Since `DataFrame` is a matrix, `write.table` is writing the output to different rows in the excel sheet. I would like that to happen in a single row.
Basically date should come in a column and entire feature importance should come in the adjoining column in the same row.

Any help in getting this done would be appreciated.

Comment: Will something like `c(Importance[row(Importance)[ ,1], ])` not be helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this. However it didn't work. Feature importance is still spread across different rows.

Comment: Have a look on the answer, please. The proposed approach has worked under the assumptions I made. But I'm nor sure that understand all the details of your `Importance` data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you in a proper way, your want to transform your `Importance_matrix` to a single row. The simplest way to do this is to unlist:

```
Importance_to_df <- unlist(as.data.frame(Importance_matrix))
DataFrame <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date(), t(Importance_to_df))
```

I wasn't sure about structure of the `Importance_matrix` and have assumed that it's a two-column matrix with the columns named `"%IncMSE"` and `"IncNodePurity"`.

Comment: I tried. Now the Importance matrix is spread across different cols and coming up in two rows, with top row containing header. I was thinking of a way in which the entire importance matrix is inserted into a single cell adjacent to the date col.

Comment: Then add, please, an example of a desired csv-output to your question. Otherwise it's difficult to guess what is your purpose. Probably, the output file just should contain different separators between the date values and other parameters?